# Spotfire Custom Expression summarizing over dates and unique identifiers

Tags: expression, tibco, spotfire

I am trying to make a bar chart in Spotfire where the y-axis is displayed via a custom expression with the x-axis being a year.

I am using a multiplier for each year and then summarizing. Basically, I have a large dataset and I am using a published model that says each year, only a certain percentage of these data are actually important. So I am trying to  make a bar chart with just that percentage of "important" data. When my data contains only unique records, this expression works:

```
Sum(Case  
when (Year([Date*])=2011) and ([Source]="A") then  0.43 
when (Year([Date*])=2012) and ([Source]="A") then  0.44 
when (Year([Date*])=2013) and ([Source]="A") then  0.45 
when (Year([Date*])=2014) and ([Source]="A") then  0.47 
when (Year([Date*])=2015) and ([Source]="A") then  0.48
else 0 
end)
```

However, my data does contain some duplicate records. For instance, my data looks something like this:

```
ID    Source    Date*       TA
1     A         1/2/2013   C
1     A         1/2/2013   D
2     A         3/5/2015   E
3     A         11/15/2012 B
3     A         11/15/2012 C
4     B         2/15/2014  B
```

If I used the above working code, I would end up double counting for record IDs 1 and 3. Note I also have data with a `Source <> A`, but I do not want to include those in the chart.

I have tried something like this, but it is just completely wrong:

```
Sum(Case  
when (Year([Date*])=2011) and ([Source]="A") then UniqueCount([ID]) * 0.43 
when (Year([Date*])=2012) and ([Source]="A") then UniqueCount([ID]) * 0.44 
when (Year([Date*])=2013) and ([Source]="A") then UniqueCount([ID]) * 0.45 
when (Year([Date*])=2014) and ([Source]="A") then UniqueCount([ID]) * 0.47 
when (Year([Date*])=2015) and ([Source]="A") then UniqueCount([ID]) * 0.48
else 0 
end)
```

How do I sum over different percentages by year and unique identifier? Do I need to consider some kind of over statement after my `then`? I'm stuck and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Which version of Spotfire?

Comment: @scsimon - Spotfire 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this should work:

```
UniqueCount([ID]) * 
Avg(Case  
when (Year([Date*])=2011) and ([Source]="A") then 0.43 
when (Year([Date*])=2012) and ([Source]="A") then 0.44 
when (Year([Date*])=2013) and ([Source]="A") then 0.45 
when (Year([Date*])=2014) and ([Source]="A") then 0.47 
when (Year([Date*])=2015) and ([Source]="A") then 0.48
else 0
end)
```

Essentially you are using the unique count to sum the unique IDs which are split into years based on your x-axis.  Then you are multiplying this count by the number you specified in your case statement.  The Avg is needed as the value needs to be aggregated for the visualization to work properly.

Comment: This works great for the limited data I gave in the example. It even works great for relatively small sample sizes. But, when I expand this out to my actual data, it doesn't work. It starts to deviate at about 100 rows (but I don't think I can put that much data in my question). My data is about 250,000 rows so the difference is pretty great at that level. I _think_ that by taking the average, you're losing the distribution of data by year.

Comment: Hmmm, if that's not working then an alternate solution would be to move the case statement to a calculated column, add RowID, and then flag the first record of each repeated element.  I've added another answer which details this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

(1) Add a calculated column (Data Cleaning Value) that assigns the values from your case statement:

```
Case  
when (Year([Date*])=2011) and ([Source]="A") then 0.43 
when (Year([Date*])=2012) and ([Source]="A") then 0.44 
when (Year([Date*])=2013) and ([Source]="A") then 0.45 
when (Year([Date*])=2014) and ([Source]="A") then 0.47 
when (Year([Date*])=2015) and ([Source]="A") then 0.48
else 0
```

(2) Add a calculated column (RowID) for RowID:

```
RowID()
```

(3) Add a calculated column (Cleaned Data) which flags the first row of each duplicate value record set and returns the value from the case statement for that record:

```
If([RowId]=Min([RowId]) over ([ID]),[Data Cleaning  Value],null)
```

(4) Create your bar chart with date on the x-axis and sum([Cleaned Data]) on the y-axis.

When I did this with the data you provided the resultant plot was the same as that driven by the custom expression in my other answer.  Without additional data though I wasn't able to test if it would on a larger data set.